# Telegramerror: 403: forbidden: bot was blocked by the user NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Юзер заблочил бота,из за этого получаемые данные для json файла undefined,try catch не сделает это так как не является ошибкой.
И бот сразу падает с такой ошибкой

```
TelegramError: 403: Forbidden: bot was blocked by the user
at C:\Users\sashuha\Desktop\botjs\node_modules\telegraf\core\network\client.js:281:17
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
```

code: 403,

Comment: Фразы «не является ошибкой» и «падает с такой ошибкой» противоречат друг другу. Покажите хоть код, который падает?

Comment: Как отлавливать ошибки и исключения почитать можно [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling)